# Could not find the ColdFusion component or interface

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11, mura

I had a Mura 5 site, Admin stopped working with CF11 update.
I downloaded Mura 6, pasted site content in it, applied updateDB from url to the old database and it updated the DB.

Now admin area is working but i am getting the following error on client area.

> Could not find the ColdFusion component or interface C:\sites\mura\test_site1\includes\servlet.cfc.
>
> Ensure that the name is correct and that the component or interface exists.

The only problem is it is looking in old folder name **mura** instead of root folder of site which I named **mura-6**.

I don't know where can i change that to fix it. I didn't find any settings in tsetting nor in settings.ini.cfm(this has an abort tag on start btw)
I have also applied appreload, fuseboxreload and there is no mapping i found.

please guide.

Comment: It is probably either in `application.cfc` of in CF admin mapping settings. You need to add more debug information so that it can be evaluated

Comment: @JamesAMohler Thanks for your reply. I updated the Core files once more, and did a reload. Also there was a bug mentioned on Mura forum applied that fix. And now its working. Thanks :)

Comment: you should provide some of the details to the bug so that if someone else comes to this question, they get useful information.